# How do I export a game from Stencyl to Xcode?

Tags: xcode, game-engine, stencyl

When I run Test Game to an iOS Device, the source code that opens in Xcode is not being updated.  I see code from the last time I successfully saved and ran.

It used to work perfectly and I not sure what changed.  This is happening in both Stencyl 2.2.0 and 3.0.0.

Any help would be much appreciated as I am very eager to put the finishing touches on my first game.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something I've found, with Stencyl 3.0, is if you build for iOS device or for simulator, it no longer opens Xcode to launch the app, but it does still create the xcodeproj.

What I do, is build, then immediately use spotlight search (command space) and search for ".xcodeproj" - the most recently updated will be the one created by Stencyl.